# How can I configure canonical URLs to point back to the original node from its related comment/reply pages?

Tags: 7, comments, uri

I have a Drupal 7 site where comments are turned on. However, all the comment/reply pages are reproducing the content from the main article. In addition, all the canonical urls in the source code point to the address for that comment/reply page.

Here is an example

Node:  http://seesapporo.com/dining/soup-curry-yellow

comment/reply above article: http://seesapporo.com/comment/reply/1315

How can I configure the canonicals for comment/reply pages to point back to their node they originate from?

Comment: Are you using [Metatag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag)?

Comment: @Mołot I am using Metatag yes.